# Using Material UI's Button component with enctype

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

So I am planning on using Multer to upload images. And I am using Material UI's button component `onClick` prop. to submit the data. Does me wrapping the button component in a form tag accomplish the same thing? If not how do I specify how the form data should be encoded?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={this.onSubmit}
                  round
                  className={classes.footerButtons}
                >
                  Post
                </Button>
                <div className={classes.footerButtons}>
                  <ImageUpload />
                </div>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jsx the enctype attribute should be encType="multipart/form-data".

onSubmit would need to be on the form element and the button should have type="submit".

Would look something like this:

```
<form
  method="post"
  action=""
  encType="multipart/form-data"
  onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
>
  <Button
    type="submit"
  > Submit
  </Button>
</form>
```

Comment: The Material UI API for button doesn't have a prop for `type` though.

Comment: The Button component in mui is actually just the native button element so you can use the type attribute. You can see this with the chrome dev tools.